# Implementing pagination

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

I have the following action

```
public ActionResult ViewModelProducts()
        {
            var listOfProductsBuy = db.ProductsBuy.Select(x => new ProductBuyViewModel
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Title = x.Title,
                ProductBuyId = x.Id,
                Author = x.Author,
                MasterImageUrl = x.Images.FirstOrDefault().Url,
                Price = x.Price,
                Values = x.Value,

            }).ToList();
            var listOfProductsRent = db.ProductsRent.Select(y => new ProductRentViewModel
            {
                Id = y.Id,
                Title = y.Title,
                MasterImageUrl = y.ImagesRent.FirstOrDefault().Url,
                ProductRentId = y.Id,
                Author = y.Author,
                Period = y.Period.PeriodOfTime,
                Price = y.Price,
                Values = y.Value,
            }).ToList();

            var listOfProductsSearch = db.ProductSearches.Select(z => new ProductSearchViewModel
            {
                Id = z.Id,
                Title = z.Title,
                ProductSearchId = z.Id,
                Author = z.Author,
                MasterImageUrl = z.ImagesSearch.FirstOrDefault().Url,
                Price = z.Price,
                Values = z.Value,
            }).ToList();

            var viewModel = new AllProductsViewModel { ProductBuy = listOfProductsBuy, ProductRent = listOfProductsRent, ProductSearch = listOfProductsSearch};
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

I want to implement paging for more than one viewmodel. If there is way with PagedList it will be better, but if there is not it will be ok too.

Comment: Could you explain more what "paging for more than on viewmodel." means ?

Comment: I have three viewmodels, but I have one view which dispaly them. And want to make pagination for those three viewmodels.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add paging, you can install PagedList.MVC Nuget package. You can see the exact step by step procedure to add it on Microsoft website [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). Check out the section named: "Add Paging to the Students Index Page". Hope this helps.